# Deploying two different WARs to Jboss 5.1

Tags: web-server, jboss

Is this a possibility? Unfortunately we are stuck with using JBoss 5.1.

We have one application running on it, but I want to deploy a separate application and I'm trying to put together my options on doing this.

All documentation I'm finding is for JBoss 7.1.

Comment: It seems that the older community releases are harder to find documentation for, but this looks like something that might help you: http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/5-x (even though it says AS 7 on the title the docs really seem to be for 5.x)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such limit, just copy the file and if autodeploy is on - after few seconds it will load application automatically, otherwise you just need to restart service.